# Dynamic templating and decoraiton in VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have VUE `Field` and `Form` components which renders a form depending on dynamic data.

```vue
<template> 
  <form @submit="$emit('submit', $event)" >
    <template v-for="(item, index) in form.elements">     
      <Field
        v-model="value[index]" 
        :label="item.options.label"  
        :type="item.type"      
      />
    </template>
  </form>
</template>
```

I can render a form by passing structure data

```vue
<Form :form="formStructure" v-model="state" @submit="save()" />
```

This renders the from elements with the order in the `formStructure` object

What I want to do is to add a decoration template to `Form` component and customize the view.

```vue
<Form :form="formStructure" v-model="state" @submit="save()" >
  <template >
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"><i class="icon-user"></i> <!-- Field component will be render here by Form componenet --> </div>
        <div class="col-8"><i class="icon-mail"></i> <!-- Field component will be render here by Form componenet  -->     </div>
     </div>
     <h2>A Custom Header</h2>
     <div class="row">
       <!-- another row with other elements-->
     </div>
  </template>
</Form>
```

formStructure data is someting like

```json
{
   "form":{
      "method":"post",
      "id":"formF75a1543a"
   },
   "elements":{
      "username":{
         "type":"inputtext",
         "options":{
            "label":"Pick a username"
         }
      },
      "email":{
         "type":"inputtext",
         "options":{
            "label":"Your e-mail"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: use named [slots](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#slot-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after a long research. Slots are not enough to solve the problem. Teleport will do the trick.

```vue
<!-- The Form Component -->
<template> 
  <form @submit="$emit('submit', $event)" >
   <slot name="default" ></slot>  
    <template v-for="(item, index) in form.elements">     
     <teleport :to="'#'+index" :disabled="!fieldTargetExists(index)">
      <Field
        v-model="value[index]" 
        :label="item.options.label"  
        :type="item.type"      
      />
      </teleport>
    </template>
  </form>
</template>
```

```vue
<!-- Using component with a template -->
<Form :form="formStructure" v-model="state" @submit="save()" >
  <template >
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"><i class="icon-user"></i> <span id="username"></span> </div>
        <div class="col-8"><i class="icon-mail"></i> <span id="email"></span> </div>
     </div>
     <h2>A Custom Header</h2>
     <div class="row">
       <div id="submit"></div>
     </div>
  </template>
</Form>
```